# Write data to SSD1306 via I2C

Tags: arduino, avr, led

I'm using an SSD1306 OLED and have a question about it.

When writing data to its buffer via I2C, some libraries write 16 bytes every time.

For example:

```c
void SSD1306::sendFramebuffer(const uint8_t *buffer) {
  // Set Column Address (0x00 - 0x7F)
  sendCommand(SSD1306_COLUMNADDR);
  sendCommand(0x00);
  sendCommand(0x7F);
  // Set Page Address (0x00 - 0x07)
  sendCommand(SSD1306_PAGEADDR);
  sendCommand(0x00);
  sendCommand(0x07);
  for (uint16_t i = 0;i < SSD1306_BUFFERSIZE;) {
    i2c.start();
    i2c.write(0x40);
    for (uint8_t j = 0;j < 16; ++j, ++i) {
      i2c.write(buffer[i]);
    }
    i2c.stop();
  }
}
```

Why don't they write 1024 bytes directly?

Comment: It's not a hardware issue. Some (Arduino) I²C libraries just buffer the data you give them until you end the transmission. To avoid excessive buffer use it may make sense to send smaller chunks.

Comment: mmmmar, Thanks for accepting my answer.  If you'll press the up-arrow to upvote it also, your action will make it easier for others to find this answer.

Comment: the LCD itself has no limit on I2C transfer (limit is on SW I2C implementation on ARDUINO side) you can copy entire VRAM at once ... however it has the same HW bug as ARDUINO SW I2C lib (sending ACK signals once per packet instead of once per BYTE) the LCD is unusable with correct HW/SW I2C implementations. Had to make my own just to workaround this issue on AVR32 (took me weeks to analyze what was happening) Also it has no commands for resetting the VRAM address pointer making it unreliable in long therm usage as any transfer corruption will shift the image until VCC power on/off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the I2C libraries I've seen source code for, including that for the Aruduino, chunk the data in this fashion.  While the I2C standard doesn't require this, as other poster mentioned, there may be buffer considerations.  The `.stop()` command here might signal the device to process the 16 bytes just sent and prepare for more.

Invariably, **you need to read the datasheet for your device** and understand what it expects in order to display properly.  They say "RTFM" in software, but hardware is at least as unforgiving.  You must read and follow the datasheet when interfacing with external hardware devices.

Answer (score 0):

Segmenting data into more frames helps when the receiving device has not enough buffer space or is simply not fast enough to digest the data at full rate. The START/STOP approach might give the receiving device a bit of time to process the received data. In your specific case, the 16-byte chunks seem to be exactly one line of the display.

Other reasons for segmenting transfers are multi-master operations, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Just streaming the data to its DRAM the SSD1306 will accept any amount of data at the maximum supported bus speed. (BT, DT.)

Comment: In this specific case, as we are talking about a display that is prone to screen flicker when modifying a line that is just being transferred to the screen, it could also easily be that you can evade this by sending out line by line info.

Comment: Nope. - Besides, the SSD1306's DRAM is not organized in lines.